# button appear with woocommerce status

Tags: php, woocommerce

With the following code, I'm adding a link to my order detail in WooCommerce:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'nolo_custom_field_display_cust_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function nolo_custom_field_display_cust_order_meta( WC_Order $order ) {
    echo '<a href="https://link.com.br">Request Sample</a>';
}
```

I would like this button to only appear when the order status is: `wc-processing`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the order status in the callback function, to achieve that, you can use this:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'custom_link_for_processing_orders', 10, 1 ); 

function custom_link_for_processing_orders( $order ) {

    /* 
        You can add other statuses to this array, like 'on-hold'.
        Example for multiple statuses:
        $statuses = array(
            'processing',
            'on-hold',
            'failed'
        );
    */
    $statusesWithLink = array(
        'processing'
    );

    // It checks the order status equals the statuses array items or not, and show the link if it equals
    if ( $order->has_status( $statusesWithLink ) ) {
        echo '<a href="https://link.com.br">Request Sample</a>';
    }
    
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, it worked perfectly!

Comment: @MainartM you should mark this answer in case it helped to close the question!

Comment: @MainartM Always welcome! As Mr. Jo said, please mark my answer as "Accepted" (Mark icon on the left of the answer) to close the question. I'd appreciate it if you do it, thanks!